# I cant type in the terminal , what is the problem?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I can't type the password in the terminal, can you help me?

Comment: just enter password and press enter . it will not show any thing while entering password on terminal .

Comment: You can't type or you can't see? That's a difference.

Comment: It's some sort of security measure used. You don't see your password being typed. I'm pretty sure it's to prevent it from being logged.

Answer (score 4):

Type in your password and press enter. Nothing will appear in the terminal when you type in your password.